# Php, laravel datetime comparison

Tags: php, laravel

I want to ask a question about laravel/php

I have to compare two different times and today's date with the current date.

```
$now_time=date('H');

$current_day=date('Y-m-d');
$that_date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->date));
```

Comment: not today would be `$current_day!=$that_date`

Comment: what value store in $current_time  variable?

Comment: It is $now_time @Laravel

Answer (score 2):

using carbon you can compare this 
`Carbon::today()` you can use for current date

other info go to [laracasts discussion](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-compare-a-string-with-carbon-date-if-more-than-or-less-than?page=1)